# Matching with disparate headers/multiple tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use a macro to combine a few hundred reports. The issue is that columns get moved around as they change hands. I need to realign the headers so columns contain the same type of data. I want to bring the data to another tab with everything in the right order.

I tried a few things with index/match, but nothing seems to work. How can I align my headers? I have keywords I can use (I had to remove some sensitive data, but ID values are unique). There are also other/different origin files, I just removed them for the example.

[image]

Comment: Does the text in the headers change, or just the column order?  (i.e. does "DATE REJECTED" become other stuff like "Date Loan was Rejected", or does it *always* say "DATE REJECTED" even if it's in Column A, Q, Z, etc)

Comment: Only the order changes. The same text is used for all the headers.